# Why Umbraco replace hostname/subdomain in external link

Tags: asp.net, umbraco7

I am using webforms with Umbraco 7.6.3 I have simple menu(not using template)  on my master page (/masterpages/Master.master) like this:

```
     <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a runat="server" href="https://sub1.test.mywebsite">Home</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
```

if I don't add www In href Umbraco replace hostname/subdomain.
Am I missing any setting?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm. You have to have a protocol, like http or https, in front of your link. So https://www.google.com is a valid link.

Comment: Links come in two "variants": relative or absolute. If you want to link to a page on your own website, you can use a relative path, but anything external has to be an absolute path. External paths must have a protocol and include the domain you are pointing to, whether it be a subdomain or not. Use http:// if https:// is not supported. Relative links are what you will typically get from Umbraco when building your navigation.

Comment: @ jannik Anker but I don't understand why Umbraco replace subdomain/hostname in base URL. Is there a setting in webconfig file? my base URL is abctb.org.au and Umbraco seem to replace subdomain part from URL.

Comment: I'm thinking that if you don't include http/https/ftp/mailto/whateverotherprotocol in your link address, Umbraco will treat it as a relative link. Where/how are you inputting these URLs? I'm not sure I follow how you are running into this problem at all.

Comment: Where do you input these links?

Comment: You're not making any sense, sorry. Are you putting those links directly into your HTML? Then Umbraco doesn't do anything to them, end of story. If you are setting the URLs somewhere inside the Umbraco backoffice, then please share where and how.

Comment: I input these links to  /masterpages/Master.master

Comment: Then it has absolutely nothing to do with Umbraco. Could you update your question with the code in Master.master?

Comment: Try removing the runat=server from your link. It doesn't do anything. Otherwise I don't know what could cause the issue other than perhaps a redirect on the server. Sorry :-s

Comment: no joy even after removing runat=server. Thanks Jannik Anker. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need write code like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>aboutus</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```